# Error calling deposit function on ERC20 escrow contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I wrote this contract to escrow a given type of ERC20 token (address of the token is given when calling the constructor). But every time I call the deposit function to deposit some tokens into the contract, I just get transaction failed and I'm not sure why.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MainEscrow is Ownable {

    IERC20 public token;

    event Deposited(
        address indexed payee,
        address tokenAddress,
        uint256 amount
    );
    event Withdrawn(
        address indexed payee,
        address tokenAddress,
        uint256 amount
    );

    // payee address => token address => amount
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public deposits;

    // payee address => token address => expiration time
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public expirations;

    constructor(address _tokenAddress) {
        token = IERC20(_tokenAddress);
    }

    function deposit(
        address _payee,
        uint256 _amount,
        uint256 _expiration
    ) public {
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        deposits[_payee][address(token)] += _amount;
        expirations[_payee][address(token)] = block.timestamp + _expiration;
        emit Deposited(_payee, address(token), _amount);
    }

    function withdraw(address payable _payee, uint256 _amount) public {
        uint256 totalPayment = deposits[_payee][address(token)];
        require(totalPayment >= _amount, "Not enough value");
        token.approve(_payee, _amount);
        require(token.transfer(_payee, _amount));
        deposits[_payee][address(token)] = totalPayment - _amount;
        emit Withdrawn(_payee, address(token), _amount);
    }

    function refund(address payable _payee) public {
        require(
            block.timestamp > expirations[_payee][address(token)],
            "The payment is still in escrow."
        );
        uint256 payment = deposits[_payee][address(token)];
        token.approve(msg.sender, payment);
        require(token.transfer(msg.sender, payment), "Transfer failed");
        deposits[_payee][address(token)] = 0;
        emit Withdrawn(msg.sender, address(token), payment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's practically only one line that could fail in the `deposit()` function:

```
token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
```

*(It could theoretically also revert because of an integer overflow on the following two lines, but this is very improbable.)*

This line executes the function `tranferFrom()` on the `token` contract. As the [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) standard defines, the function should revert if the token sender doesn't have sufficient balance, or if they haven't approved the caller (in your case the `MainEscrow` address) to spend that much of their tokens.

So either the token sender doesn't have sufficient balance, or they haven't called the `approve(<MainEscrow_address>, <amount>)` function from their address on the token contract.

Comment: Thanks I was missing the approve function.